# what is this perl expression "$DEBUG>=3 && DEBUG("OK=$ok");"?

Tags: perl

what is this perl expression ""?

```
$DEBUG>=3 && DEBUG("OK=$ok");
```

What make me so confused is mainly the bool operation "&&".Any one can explain it for me?Thanks .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is the same as:

```
if( $DEBUG >= 3 ) {
   DEBUG("OK=$ok");
}
```

or

```
DEBUG("OK=$ok") if $DEBUG >= 3;
```

I personally prefer this one (it's more readable for me)

**Explanation:**

`Sentence1 && Sentence2`

`Sentence2` will be performed only if `Sentence1` is true. The && operator is a logical AND, so if the first sentence is false, the complete operation will be false (it's no neccesary to evaluate the second sentence)

Comment: Of course chances are the developer who wrote that expression was flying by the seat of his/her pants because of the risks of misunderstanding operator precedence. I've witnessed production code that failed because the developer didn't understand that `&&` binds tightly while `and` binds loosely. In this kind of expression `and` would be preferable given its low operator precedence; however a cautious developer would use parenthesis to make it absolutely clear, irrespective of precedence rules, what binds to what.

Comment: Another question ,if I change "&&" to "||",what does it mean ?

Comment: If you put `||` it will only execute the `DEBUG()` part if `$DEBUG` is not greater or equal than 3 because of the logical OR. The right hand side of `||` is only executed if the left hand side expression is not true. Also with tighter binding than `or`.

Answer (score 1):

$DEBUG must be at 3 or more and the `return` Value from the `sub DEBUG` must be `true` as well. `True` means, that its not

- undef
- 0
- ""
- "0"
- Any blessed objects that overload conversion to boolean to return false
- Empty arrays and empty hashes

Boolean parts with subs will be executed as well. So that if your expression is inside an `if` clause, the `return` value will be the part of that expression. Eg.

```
sub test {
    return 1;
}

if ( $abc >2 && test() ) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Since this is a single statement, it doesn't matter if the right hand side is true or not. Only if it's in an `if` condition it matters.

Answer (score 1):

Quoting [perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html):

> C-style Logical And
>
> Binary "&&" performs a short-circuit logical AND operation. That is,
>   if the left operand is false, the right operand is not even evaluated.
>   Scalar or list context propagates down to the right operand if it is
>   evaluated.

Comment: Another question ,if I change "&&" to "||",what does it mean ?

Comment: `Binary "||" performs a short-circuit logical OR operation. That is, if the left operand is true, the right operand is not even evaluated. Scalar or list context propagates down to the right operand if it is evaluated.`

Answer (score 0):

The `&&` is an *and* operator. However, like `C`, Perl uses a logic shortcut. If the left hand side is false, you know the whole statement is false, so you don't have to test the right hand side. However, if the left hand side is true, you have to test the right hand side to make sure the entire statement is true.

Thus if `$DEBUG >= 3` is true, the right hand side `$OK = "ok"` will be executed. It's the same as:

```
if ( $DEBUG >= 3 ) {
    $OK = "ok";
}
```

And, I would argue, it is better to write it out the long way just like I did<sup>1</sup>. Even if you knew what `&&` does in a logic statement, it takes your brain a few milliseconds of processing to figure out what `$DEBUG>=3 && $OK="ok";` is doing. Yet, it's probably no faster to execute than writing it out the long way.

Somewhere in the future, some poor System Application Programmer (aka sap) has to go in and maintain the code. If the code is bogged down with tightly written cryptic statements, it will be a bear to maintain.

---

<sup>1</sup> And don't even think of writing `$OK = "ok" if $DEBUG >= 3;`. This is not a case for a post-fixed if statement.